# I get an error message when i try to parse an XML response using REST assured

Tags: rest-assured

Iam using this simple function to get and print out the value at an XML response:

```
@Test

    void validateXMLResponse() {

        String book = RestAssured.given().when()
                .get("https://chercher.tech/sample/api/books.xml")
                .then().extract().path("bookstore.book.title");
        System.out.println(book);

    }
```

But iam getting this error in the console:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class io.restassured.internal.path.xml.NodeChildrenImpl cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (io.restassured.internal.path.xml.NodeChildrenImpl is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have more than book node in your xml, you should use corresponding index to define which book's title you want to get. Like this: "*bookstore.book[0].title*". Or iterate through index to get all the books titles.

```
    @Test
    public void validateXMLResponse() {
        String book = RestAssured.given().when()
                .get("https://chercher.tech/sample/api/books.xml")
                .then().extract().body().path("bookstore.book[0].title");
        System.out.println(book);
    }
```